# In Swift, is There an Equivalent of passUnretained() for Value Types?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I'm trying to do some basic proofs, and, as such, I'd like to be able to get the memory locations of variables and constants.

Here's a simple example of the kind of thing that I'm looking at:

```
import Foundation

class A {
    var a: Int = 0
    let b: Int = 3

    var description: String {
        return "a: is \"\(a)\", b is \"\(b)\""
    }
}

struct B {
    var a: Int = 0
    let b: Int = 3

    var description: String {
        return "a: is \"\(a)\", b is \"\(b)\""
    }
}

let classInstance = A()
let structInstance = B()

print(Unmanaged.passUnretained(classInstance).toOpaque())
print(Unmanaged.passUnretained(structInstance).toOpaque())
```

The issue is with the second `print(Unmanaged.passUnretained(structInstance).toOpaque())`

I'm told that I can't pass the struct constant in.

Fair 'nuff. [The docs say](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unmanaged/1538637-passunretained) so:

**Declaration**

```
static func passUnretained(_ value: Instance) -> Unmanaged<Instance>
```

**Parameters**

- **value** *A class instance.*

**Return Value** *An unmanaged reference to the object passed as value.*

As you can see, it insists on a class instance.

My question is that I'd like to be able to view the memory address of the struct, as well.

The reason for this, is that I am trying to create a playground that illustrates how the entire struct gets moved around if you change a member var.

I am using Swift 4.2.

**EDIT**

Ah. Now I remember.

It's important that the values be instantiated using `let` (constant). The whole idea is to show that the actual struct gets copied when a data member is modified.

We'll assume that all the above holds true until the two `let` declarations:

```
withUnsafePointer(to: classInstance) { print("value \(classInstance) has address: \($0)") }
withUnsafePointer(to: structInstance) { print("value \(structInstance) has address: \($0)") }
```

Works, but displays the same address for both:

```
value __lldb_expr_5.A has address: 0x00007ffee462ed38
value B(a: 0, b: 3) has address: 0x00007ffee462ed38
```

If I try sending in references:

```
withUnsafePointer(to: &classInstance) { print("value \(classInstance) has address: \($0)") }
withUnsafePointer(to: &structInstance) { print("value \(structInstance) has address: \($0)") }
```

I get yelled at by the compiler. Basically, the issue Martin wrote about.

Comment: Eh, you want to reference value of non-reference type?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to look at its memory location.

Comment: That could be on the stack or the heap. I can see it in the debugger, but that doesn't help.

Comment: A struct is a non-reference type, It is not possible to see memory address for a non-reference type.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I'm expecting. Swift goes out of its way to hide that stuff.
Just wanted to find out if it was possible.

Comment: Why aren’t you using `withUnsafePointer`?

Comment: @matt: Interestingly, `withUnsafePointer(to: structInstance)` does make a copy (as observed here: https://forums.swift.org/t/fastest-way-to-get-const-pointer-to-struct-for-inter-operability-with-c-c/19156/3) – that might be a bug. – `withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &structInstance) { print($0)}` seems to  work, but requires a *variable.*

Comment: @matt: I did. The weird thing is that I get exactly the same result, no matter what I send in. I'll create another playground and update my question with that. What Martin wrote might solve that.

Comment: Remember that a struct might not even *have* a memory location. Anything smaller than `Int` can be optimized to a register (or even optimized into immediate values). And changing a struct is not required to cause it to move in memory. Beyond the common copy-on-write case, the optimizer is free to note that the previous value is never referenced again and make a modification in place. A common optimization is to replace trivial modifications with a single `.init` that assigns the final values.

Comment: @Rob Napier Great point. Also, I know that a big driver for Swift is security. Abstracting away from the internals is a good way to enforce security.